# User input multiplies if user refresh the page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have created a page for creating a post in laravel . it works well . but when I refresh the thanks giving page again data is inserted .

MY create.blade.php is :

```
<div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
{{ Form::open(array('action'=>'create','method'=>'PUT')) }}

{{ Form::label('title','Title :') }}<br>
{{ Form::text('title','',array('required')) }}<br>

{{ Form::label('body','Post :') }}<br>
{{ Form::textarea('body','',array('required')) }}<br>

{{ Form::label('user_id','User Id :')}}<br>
{{ Form::text('user_id','',array('required')) }}<br>

{{ Form::label('done','Status :') }}<br>
{{ Form::text('done','',array('required')) }}<br><br>

{{ Form::submit() }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

my route file is:

`Route::get('/','TasksController@home');
Route::get('/create','TasksController@create');
Route::post('/create','TasksController@createpost');`

taskController is :

```
class TasksController extends BaseController{

    public function home(){
        $tasks = Task::all();
        return View::make('home',compact('tasks'));
    }

    public function create(){
        return View::make('create');
    }

    public function createpost(){

        $input = Input::all();
        $task = new Task;

        $task->title = $input['title'];
        $task->body = $input['body'];
        $task->user_id = $input['user_id'];
        $task->done = $input['done'];
        $task->save();

        return View::make('thanks');
    }

}
```

and thanks.blade.php is :

Thanks for registering

I want that if a user refresh the thanks.blade.php then will not insert again in the database

Thanks

Comment: Instead of returning a view, redirect to it.  If you want to pass along a message then use Session::flash().  Another option is to include a hidden field in the form that contains a token.  Store that token along with the post data in the database.  In createpost() you then check to see if a post exists with that token, which would indicate a page refresh.  Using a redirect sure is much simpler though.

Answer (score 3):

On page refresh, the form is submitted again every time by the browser. I usually use redirect after form submit. You can do this using header() function, for example.

Or you can redirect with a message in laravel like this:

```
return Redirect::to('thanks')->with('message', 'My message here');
```

Comment: You were right @RobertRozas . I updated my answer. I hope it suits you

Comment: but then I will have to create a route for this . what if anyone enter a url like this www.example.com/thanks . then he will see the thanks message directly . if there is any to show the message only when the user has performed the post submission . And thansks diana for your help

Comment: But you can make some restrictions in thanks.blade.php file. For example, you can send a variable along with redirect and display content in the view only if that variable is set.

Comment: I also thought so . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

After submitting, use `redirect()` function :

```
return redirect('make');
```